# compiling invalid oracle procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a wrapper procedure(proc_main) that calls some procedures within.

```
create or replace Procedure proc_main
as
begin

proc_child1;

proc_child2;

proc_child3;

proc_compile_invalids; -- This invokes "alter procedure <procedure_name> compile" statement for all the invalids.

end;
/
```

proc_child procedures apply some processing logic that involves some steps to rename the tables within.

This invalidates the procedures which is the reason why I have the proc_compile_invalids procedure to set them to a valid state again.

My problem is: when I execute the proc_main procedure, it invalidates the main procedure along with the inner child ones.
Hence, When the proc_compile_invalids is called as a last step, it hangs as it is trying to recompile the main calling procedure.

Obviously, it is not an issue if i remove the last step and execute it separately.

I know I could separate them out as 2 different calls by commenting the compile proc and executing it as a stand alone. 
And i also am aware it is a cosmetic step as oracle would try to compile a procedure before executing the next time. So, the invalids become valid anyway.
But, at the end of the execution for that day, they all are in an invalid state and I get questioned by the powers be if it can be avoided !

So, just wanted to know if I can avoid separating the calls and still retain it as a last step in the main procedure.

Any thoughts/pointers much appreciated.

Comment: It's best to avoid renaming tables in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) to break the dependency:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_main AS
BEGIN

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN proc_child1; END;';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN proc_child2; END;';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN proc_child3; END;';

   proc_compile_invalids;  -- This invokes 
                           -- "alter procedure <procedure_name> compile" 
                           -- statement for all the invalids.

END;
```

Comment: OP: My problem is: when I execute the proc_main procedure, it invalidates the main procedure along with the inner child ones. - how does this solution avoid the invalidation of the calling proc?

Comment: The `proc_main` procedure will not be invalidated if coded like this because it is not dependent upon the objects modified.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked with a minor tweak. The semi-colon (;) at the end of the "END" was missing from your post. It should be EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN proc_child3; END;'; But, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle 11g onward

You can use `compile_schema` procedure of [dbms_utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm) package instead of `proc_compile_ivalids` in your main procedure to recompile all invalid procedures, functions, packages, and triggers in the specified schema

```
create or replace Procedure proc_main
as
begin
  Proc_child1;
  proc_child2;
  proc_child3;
  dbms_utility.compile_schema(schema, false);
end;
```

Comment: `dbms_utility.compile_schema` will hang if it tried to compile `proc_main` while it is running, won't it?

Comment: No it will not hang. Because to get proc_main running it already must be compiled without an error. Second parameter of comile_schema set to false, it means that we will only consider invalid objects not valid ones. And Proc_main must be valid in order to start recompilation process.

Comment: One of the `proc_child` procedure will invalidate `proc_main`. `dbms_utility.compile_schema` will try to recompile `proc_main` and this will hang because the procedure is still running, at least on 9iR2. However, the behaviour seems to have changed in later versions: in 11gR2 the `compile_schema` procedure will not recompile `proc_main` and will therefore not hang. The `proc_main` procedure will be left invalidated.

Comment: Yes Vincent, I've assumed by default that the version of RDBMS is 11g onward and that was the matter of disagreements.

Comment: It's always interesting to see the little changes between versions :) I upvoted your answer but still, it doesn't really answer the OP's problem of having its procedure left invalidated at the end.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original question post...my version was oracle 11g...But, all's good now...!