# Running DDL within Oracle Procedure - ORA-06508 - How to recompile on runtime?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, ddl

I have an oracle procedure which calls few other procedures.

PROCEDURE1
 
  PROCEDURE2
  PROCEDURE3
  ..

Now what happens is that `PROCEDURE2` is performing DDL (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DDL PROCESS'` ) on some dependent tables being used in subsequent procedures 3 and onwards. This runs fine until it hits `PROCEDURE3` where it throws `ORA-06508 - Program / Unit being called not found`.

We can not modify it not to use DDL, We have to use them. I have tried recompiling after DDL statements but it does not work (`ALTER PROCEDURE PROCEDURE3 RECOMPILE`) neither in `PROCEDURE1` or in `PROCEDURE2`.

I doubt that `PROCEDURE1` itself becomes invalid and compiling that on runtime will cause endless loop. I have tried, does not works.

So I need to use some trick that can make these procedures valid again on runtime after DDL is done on dependent objects.

Thanks in advance for whoever participates to answer.

Comment: you should try to call the procedures from anonymous bloks.

Comment: @user1881540: What ddl changes you are doing,like creating a table ? and using that table in procedure 3 .Please post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, as in many other cases, would be better to create a package instead of a bunch of stand-alone procedures. Packages break dependency chain. Here is an example:

```
    SQL> create table tb_t(
     2    col1 number
     3  )
     4  ;

    Table created
```

1. Stand-alone procedures

   ```
   SQL> create or replace procedure Proc1
     2  is
     3  begin
     4    execute immediate 'alter table tb_t add (col2 number)';
     5  end;
     6  /
   ```

   Procedure created

   ```
   SQL> create or replace procedure Proc2
    2  is
    3    l_var number;
    4  begin
    5    select count(*)
    6      into l_var
    7      from tb_t;
    8    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_var));
    9  end;
    10  /

    Procedure created

    SQL> begin
     2    proc1;
     3    proc2;
     4  end;
     5  /
   ```

and we are getting

```
     ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called
```

1. Package

   ```
   SQL> create or replace package test_pkg
     2  is
     3    procedure proc1;
     4    procedure proc2;
     5  end;
     6  /

   Package created

   SQL> create or replace package body test_pkg
     2  is
     3    procedure proc1
     4    is
     5    begin
     6      execute immediate 'alter table tb_t add (col3 number)';
     7    end;
     8  
     9    procedure proc2
    10    is
    11     l_var number;
    12    begin
    13      select count(*)
    14        into l_var
    15        from tb_t;
    16      dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_var));
    17    end;
    18  
    19  end;
    20  /

    Package body created


    SQL> begin
      2    test_pkg.proc1;
      3    test_pkg.proc2;
      4  end;
      5  /

      0

      PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
   ```

Comment: What if I do not want to create a package ?

Comment: Can you find another approach on this one.

Comment: @user1881540 `What if I do not want to create a package`. Why not? If you really really do not want to create a package, you can use `execute immediate` statement (`execute immediate begin proc1; end;`(for each procedure in a pl/sql block)), which breaks dependency tracking as well. [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409189/compiling-invalid-oracle-procedures/12409857#12409857). But it would be better to use a package.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter procedure PX3 compile; -- not "recompile"
```

This works as expected:

```
set serveroutput ON

create table X as select 42 A from DUAL;

create procedure PX3
as
  a int;
begin
  select max(A) into a from X;
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
end;
/

create procedure PX2
as
begin
  execute immediate 'alter table X add (B int)';
  execute immediate 'alter procedure PX3 compile';
  PX3;
end;
/

create procedure PX1
as
begin
  PX2;
end;
/

begin
  PX1;
end;
/

drop procedure PX1;
drop procedure PX2;
drop procedure PX3;
drop table X;
```

Comment: This does not works. I have already tried using the compile statement

Comment: Well, the code I provided works when put into a file testcase.sql and executed in SQL*Plus while connected to an Oracle 9 server.
Does it work on your system? If it works, what are you doing differently in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Oracle 9 is more strict about dependency and invalidation compared to Oracle >=10.

I had a few cases in Oracle 9 of procedures and/or packages doing DDL on tables they depend on.
I came to the conclusion that the most practical solution is to make them *not* dependent on those tables.
I.e. instead of doing static SQL

```
select COL1 into my_var from MY_CHANGING_TABLE ...;
```

do it as dynamic SQL

```
execute immediate 'select COL1 from MY_CHANGING_TABLE ...' into my_var;
```